# Scrapy multiple domains and start urls

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a simple `Sracpy` spider that exports all pages in a domain to an individual csv file. Most people recommend writing a different spider for each site, but given how simple the information is that I am requesting I thought it made sense to figure out how to iterate through a list of domains. There will eventually be thousands of domains I want to get links from, all with very different structures so I would like the spider to scale.

Here are a couple lines from the csv the spider is pulling domains from:

[image]

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from NONPROF.items import NonprofItem
from scrapy.http import Request
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'C:/listofdomains.csv'
open_list = pd.read_csv(file_path)
urlorgs = open_list.urls.tolist()

open_list2 = pd.read_csv(file_path)
domainorgs = open_list2.domain.tolist()

class Nonprof(CrawlSpider):
    name = "responselist"
    allowed_domains = domainorgs
    start_urls = urlorgs

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=['.*']),
             callback='parse_item',
             follow=True)
        ]

    def parse_item (self, response):
        item = NonprofItem()
        item['responseurl'] = response.url
        yield item
```

I don't get an apparent errors when running the spider but it doesn't appear to be yielding anything: `[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)`

So I have a few questions:
1. Is scrapy capable of processing a request like this? 
2. Is there a better way to get the spider to iterate through a list of domains and matching start_url?

Comment: Please show couple of lines from your CSV file

Comment: @gangabass made the suggested edits

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you're not using start_request method!

and then you can prioritize each url

Here's a sample code that works:

```
"""
For allowed_domains:
Let’s say your target url is https://www.example.com/1.html, 
then add 'example.com' to the list.
"""
class crawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawler_name"

    allowed_domains, urls_to_scrape = parse_urls()
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=['.*']),
             callback='parse_item',
             follow=True)
        ]
    def start_requests(self):
        for i,url in enumerate(self.urls_to_scrape):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url.strip(),callback=self.parse_item, priority=i+1, meta={"pass_anydata_hare":1})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        response = response.css('logic')

        yield {'link':str(response.url),'extracted data':[],"meta_data":'data you passed' }
```

I recommend you to read this page for more info at scrapy

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests

Hope this helps :)